# Syntax for using an Iterator for an array of STL Lists

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, listiterator

I'm trying to make a templated HashTable Class that uses Seperate Chaining for collision resolution. My problem is that I don't know how to iterate through the list at specific array index's because I am unsure of the syntax.

I keep getting error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union 
and error C2228: left of '.push_front' must have class/struct/union

I've declared my list as a private member of the class like so:

```
list<T1> **List;
```

And have used the default constructor to pre-fill each index with a for loop.

Here is the trouble points :

```
template <typename T1>
void HashTable<T1>::Insert(T1 var)
{
    int index = HashFunction(var);
    List[index].push_front(var);
    ++LF;
    cout << "Load Factor: " << LF << endl << endl;
}


template <typename T1>
void HashTable<T1>::Delete(string key)
{
    int visited = 0;
    list<T1>::iterator iter;
    for(int i = 0; i < prime; ++i)
    {
        iter = List[i].begin();
        while((iter != List[i].end) && ((*iter)->getKey() != key)) //While iter is not at the end of the list and while ID of iter is not equal to ID being obliterated
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want just a single array of lists. Right now List[i] returns a pointer to a list<T1>, whereas you may intend List[i] to be a list<T1> itself.

Try using

```
list<T1> *List;
```

Comment: That did the trick! Wow can't believe I overlooked that. Now it seems I am getting a problem with my constructor... Is this now how it should be declared?

Comment: List[i] = new list<T1>[prime];

Comment: If you want your List variable to point to an array of list<T1>, then you should dynamically allocate it: List = new list<T1>[prime]; This creates "prime" number of list elements. Note that you need a default constructor, which is run "prime" number of times. To access a particular list in your array, do List[i].

Comment: Also, is there a reason you must use a native C++ array? Good C++ style is to use the stl vector, which is a resizable array. See here if you want more info: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-call-default-ctor.html